# Videos com qualidade e o menor tamanho possível

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html5-video

Tenho visto sites colocando um **vídeo** curto pra serem exibidos como se fossem `background` de uma div e fica muito lindo !

Alguém sabe orientar sobre como compactar ao máximo e os formatos adequados pra exibir nas ultimas versões do `chrome/firefox` sem perder muito a qualidade ?

Answer (score 1):

MP4 é suficiente para o Firefox e o Chrome. Só no mobile não vai pegar, tem que ser WebM.

Comment: @jonniehenrique podes desenvolver a resposta um pouco mais?